# How to calculate precision, recall, F1 score for my caffe model

Tags: conv-neural-network, caffe

```
Framework: Caffe
Architecture: Mobilenet-SSD
Dataset: [Caltech Padestrain Detection Dataset][1]
```

I know the formulae for precision, recall, F1 score & accuracy. I know the formulas but the problem here is automation of that

Manually I can calculate everything but the problem is with automating that for ~10k images in test dataset

Because I can see an image & compare that what is false positive etc etc. But not sure how to do with computer

Because my model might detect a person but the bounding box is little bigger(coordinates are bit off) & test dataset labels are accurate

So although the detection is happening but coordinates are not matching.

How to solve this problem to calculate precision, recall & accuracy? If this is not the correct way please propose correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm good question. I think you should define what you want to actually measure. F1 score, precision and recall are easy. Just see if a person has been detected or not, or you have a false positive and calculate things business as usual. For that use [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html).

Now about the bounding boxes, areas and coordinates. You should use a different metric! I recommend you mAP (mean Average Precision). Check out this [link](https://medium.com/@timothycarlen/understanding-the-map-evaluation-metric-for-object-detection-a07fe6962cf3) and feel free to read more about this on the internet. Good luck with your model!

An alternate option, is use the following gist [confusionMatrix_convnet_test_BatchMode(VeryFast).py](https://gist.github.com/Coderx7/3b02f6a8eb61110d7d0876e75933f98d) to build the confusion matrix using sklearn.

Comment: No, you should just pass the arrays of actual ```y``` labels and the predicted ones

Comment: array of actual labels are coordinates and are .xml file. Predicted ones I can get from model that's ok. Not understanding .xml labels part because there can be multiple labels & both `y`  & `predicted` will have a mismatch. Can you share some tutorial or something that can help me? Any resource?

Comment: Just use the mAP then. The link I shared should be sufficient to understand it. You can also take a look to https://medium.com/@yanfengliux/the-confusing-metrics-of-ap-and-map-for-object-detection-3113ba0386ef. For the porgramming part I would have to look for it on google. Take a look for your self and later we can discuss if you like. I hope it helps!